# Creating and managing multiple instances of whatsapp web js

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, object, whatsapp

I have a class in the file `whatsappWebSession`.

```
import { Client, LocalAuth } from "whatsapp-web.js";

class WhatsappWebSession {
  constructor(callback, readyCallback) {
    this.client = new Client({
      puppeteer: {
        headless: true,
        args: \[
          '--no-sandbox',
        \]
      },
      authStrategy: new LocalAuth({
        clientId: 'client-id',
        dataPath: './session.json',
      })
    });
    this.client.on('qr', (qr) =\> {
      this.qr = qr;
      callback(qr);
    });
    this.client.on('ready', () =\> {
      console.log('Client is ready!');
      readyCallback();
    });

    this.client.initialize();
  }

  getQr() {
    return this.qr;
  }

  getClient() {
    return this.client;
  }

  async destroy() {
    await this.client.destroy();
  }

  async restart() {
    await this.destroy();
    this.client = new Client();
    this.client.on('qr', (qr) => {
      this.qr = qr;
    });
    this.client.initialize();
  }
}

export default WhatsappWebSession;
```

Now on an express API call, for example `/new-client?id=client-id`.
I create a new object for this class.

What I want is something like I create several objects of this class, they remain running in the background, and I can get any client with client-id, something like session.getClient(client-id).

How to achieve this?

I've tried using the authstrategy to create a new object every time and then destroy it after the API response closes.
But it is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue by creating a singleton client Manager instance which will be responsible for storing client instances based on the unique identifier. Every time we need to send a message from a particular client, the manager will return the client based on the client's unique key.

For ease, I have used session id from `express-session` middleware as an instance's uniqueId.

Code for the manager:

```js
const { Client, LocalAuth } = require("whatsapp-web.js");
const QRCode = require("qrcode");
const { readdir } = require("fs/promises");
const { WhatsappWebSession } = require('./WhatsappWebSession')

const getDirectories = async source =>
  (await readdir(source, { withFileTypes: true }))
    .filter(dirent => dirent.isDirectory())
    .map(dirent => dirent.name);

class WhatsappSessionManager {
  sessionIdVsClientInstance = {};

  constructor() {
    this.sessionIdVsClientInstance = {};
    return this;
  }

  createWAClient = (sessionId, qrGenerationCallback, readyInstanceCallback) => {
    return new WhatsappWebSession(sessionId, qrGenerationCallback, readyInstanceCallback);
  };

  async restorePreviousSessions() {
    const directoryNames = await getDirectories(
      "../.wwebjs_auth"
    );
    const sessionIds = directoryNames.map(name => name.split("-")[1]);

    sessionIds.forEach(sessionId => {
      this.createWAClient(sessionId);
    });
  }

  getClientFromSessionId = sessionId => {
    return this.sessionIdVsClientInstance[sessionId];
  };
}

const singularWhatsappSessionManager = new WhatsappSessionManager();
module.exports = singularWhatsappSessionManager;
```

**createWAClient** - Used for creating new instance of the Whatsapp web session

**getClientFromSessionId** - Used for retrieving instance based on it's unique key

**restorePreviousSessions** - When the server restarts, use this function to load previously logged-in sessions in order to use them hassle-free.

With this approach, we will always have a single instance of `WhatsappSessionManager`, which will be used to keep a record of every session. For every corresponding get message-send request we will be able to use the desired WhatsApp session.

Comment: I tried this but  sessionIdVsClientInstance still empty, how shall I add clients to it?

Comment: Hi Parth, Please connect with me. I have something important to share with you regarding your solution. nelsonekpenyong@xiiela.com