# Whatsapp web js multiple sessions

Tags: node.js, whatsapp

I'm creating a bot using `whatsapp-web.js` and Express.

Here is my code:

```
app.post('/newWhatsappClient', async function (req, res){
 
 const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth({clientId:req.query.name}),
  
  });
    client.initialize();
 await client.on('qr',qr=>{
  res.json(qr)
});

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(client.authStrategy)
   console.log(req.query.name+'Client is ready!');

});
client.on('authenticated',(session) => {
  console.log(session) //prints undefined 
});
});
```

Now the question is how can I get all active sessions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: worked for me :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74746756/creating-and-managing-multiple-instances-of-whatsapp-web-js